# Unable to ping nodes from ansible

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to follow ansible tutorial but stuck at 'ping' module. I installed ansible in my wsl and trying to ping my windows machine via `ansible windows -m ping` and get this output below despite adding windows IP in /etc/ansible/hosts file

> 192.168.29.1 | UNREACHABLE! => {
> "changed": false,
> "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 192.168.29.1 port 22: Connection timed out",
> "unreachable": true
> }

`ansible windows -m ping`

expected results are:

> 192.168.29.1 | SUCCESS! => {
> "ansible_facts":{
> "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3"
> },
> "changed": false,
> "ping": pong
> }

Comment: Windows usually do not have an SSH server up and running for you to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

you can update your inventory file like below:

```bash
win-node ansible_host=win.node ansible_connection=winrm ansible_user=administrator ansible_password=WinPassword
```

and try to run your playbook. Here we are providing host related variables that enables ansible to connect with Windows managed nodes.

Hope this helps!